# problem when going back to old version of nodejs

Tags: node.js, typescript, next.js

I tried to upgrade the node version, rolled back the version to the old one and started getting typescript errors that weren't there before.

I understand that my question will seem stupid to many and even get disadvantages, but I really do not know much about this issue.

But now the project does not run locally with exactly the same version of the wizard (the same package.json) with which everything worked

I need to start, I will raise the typescript version in the future and solve all existing problems, but now I urgently need to solve another, and I cannot even start.

Could this also happen due to the fact that when I updated node I used the following commands, including clearing the cache as I understand it:

```
npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
```

// package.json

```
{
 "name": "projectname",
 "version": "1.0.0",
 "main": "index.js",
 "description": "project description",
 "private": true,
 "scripts": {
    "dev": "DEBUG=projectname:* DEBUG_DEPTH=5 nodemon server/server.ts",
    "build": "next build && tsc --project tsconfig.server.json",
    "start": "NODE_ENV=production LANG=en node .next/production-server/server/server.js",
    "postbuild": "cp -r static .next/",
    "analyze": "BUNDLE_ANALYZE=both yarn build"
 },
 "dependencies": {
    "@zeit/next-bundle-analyzer": "^0.1.2",
    "@zeit/next-css": "^1.0.1",
    "@zeit/next-sass": "^1.0.1",
    "@zeit/next-typescript": "^1.1.1",
    "app-root-path": "^2.1.0",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.404.0",
    "bbcode-to-react": "^0.2.9",
    "bcrypt": "^3.0.6",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "chart.js": "^2.7.3",
    "compression": "^1.7.3",
    "connect-memcached": "^1.0.0",
    "connect-memjs": "^0.2.1",
    "connect-mongo": "^2.0.1",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.3",
    "cookie-session": "^1.3.3",
    "cron": "^1.7.0",
    "cross-fetch": "^3.0.1",
    "csv-parse": "^4.4.1",
    "debug": "^4.1.1",
    "diff": "^3.5.0",
    "export-to-csv": "^0.2.1",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "express-http-proxy": "^1.5.1",
    "express-session": "^1.15.6",
    "find-remove": "^1.2.2",
    "form-data": "^3.0.0",
    "geoip-lite": "^1.3.8",
    "humps": "^2.0.1",
    "immutable": "^3.8.2",
    "js-base64": "^2.5.2",
    "json-immutable": "^0.4.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.3.0",
    "locale": "^0.1.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.10",
    "lru-cache": "^5.1.1",
    "md5": "^2.2.1",
    "mic-recorder-to-mp3": "^2.2.1",
    "moment-timezone": "0.3.0",
    "mongoose": "^5.2.9",
    "multer": "^1.3.1",
    "next": "^8.0.3",
    "next-compose-plugins": "^2.1.1",
    "next-cookies": "^1.1.2",
    "next-redux-wrapper": "^3.0.0-alpha.2",
    "next-routes": "^1.4.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.9.3",
    "nodemailer": "^4.6.8",
    "normalizr": "^3.2.4",
    "passport": "^0.4.0",
    "passport-custom": "^1.1.0",
    "passport-jwt": "^4.0.0",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "paypal-rest-sdk": "^1.8.1",
    "pmx": "^1.6.7",
    "query-string": "^6.2.0",
    "rc-slider": "^8.6.3",
    "react": "^16.8.4",
    "react-beautiful-dnd": "^9.0.2",
    "react-chartjs-2": "^2.7.4",
    "react-collapse": "^4.0.3",
    "react-copy-to-clipboard": "^5.0.1",
    "react-cropper": "^1.0.1",
    "react-csv": "^1.0.19",
    "react-datasheet": "^1.3.14",
    "react-day-picker": "^7.3.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.4",
    "react-dropzone": "^5.1.0",
    "react-flags": "^0.1.17",
    "react-ga": "^2.6.0",
    "react-google-recaptcha": "^1.0.5",
    "react-infinite-scroller": "^1.2.4",
    "react-joyride": "^2.0.5",
    "react-js-pagination": "^3.0.2",
    "react-lazy-load": "^3.0.13",
    "react-mic-record": "^1.0.6",
    "react-modal": "^3.8.1",
    "react-player": "^1.6.6",
    "react-quill": "^1.3.3",
    "react-redux": "^6.0.1",
    "react-select": "^2.1.0",
    "react-share": "^2.4.0",
    "react-sizeme": "^2.5.2",
    "react-to-print": "^2.4.0",
    "read-excel-file": "^4.0.7",
    "redux": "^4.0.0",
    "redux-form": "^8.1.0",
    "redux-saga": "^0.16.0",
    "set-value": "^3.0.0",
    "shelljs": "^0.8.2",
    "shortid": "^2.2.13",
    "slugify": "^1.3.4",
    "socket.io": "^2.2.0",
    "socket.io-client": "^2.2.0",
    "socket.io-redis": "^5.2.0",
    "twig": "^1.12.0",
    "typegoose": "^5.2.1",
    "uuid": "^3.3.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
     "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.1.0",
     "@types/body-parser": "^1.17.0",
     "@types/connect-mongo": "^0.0.38",
     "@types/cookie-parser": "^1.4.1",
     "@types/debug": "^4.1.0",
     "@types/express": "^4.16.0",
     "@types/express-session": "^1.15.10",
     "@types/mongodb": "^3.1.4",
     "@types/mongoose": "^5.2.6",
     "@types/multer": "^1.3.7",
     "@types/node": "^10.7.1",
     "@types/passport": "^0.4.6",
     "@types/passport-local": "^1.0.33",
     "@types/react": "^16.4.11",
     "@types/react-dom": "^16.0.7",
     "@types/redux-form": "^7.4.7",
     "@types/set-value": "^2.0.0",
     "@types/shortid": "^0.0.29",
     "autoprefixer": "^9.4.3",
     "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^3.1.1",
     "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
     "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.5",
     "babel-plugin-wrap-in-js": "^1.1.1",
     "css-purify-webpack-loader": "^1.0.1",
     "eslint": "^5.4.0",
     "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.11.1",
     "faker": "^4.1.0",
     "next-purgecss": "^3.0.1",
     "next-size": "^2.0.2",
     "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.1",
     "purgecss-whitelister": "^2.3.1",
     "stylelint-config-recommended": "^2.1.0",
     "tailwindcss": "^0.7.4",
     "ts-node": "^7.0.1",
     "typescript": "^3.0.1",
     "webpack-pwa-manifest": "^4.0.0"
   }
}
```

// ts-node -v =>

```
ts-node v7.0.1
node v10.19.0
typescript v3.0.1
cache "/tmp/ts-node-83......"
```

[UPDATED] I changed **"typescript": "^3.0.1"** > **"typescript": "3.0.1"**, and in project v3.0.1 now, global v3.7.5

I switch them to VSCode and it does not underline anything, I also took a commit where I made corrections when I tried to raise versions of all packages, but I used the original package.json, and now it swears at the import format (If I understand correctly, this import format goes in later versions: **import moment from 'moment-timezone'**):

```
// utils.ts:
import * as moment from 'moment-timezone';

// traceback error
/home/roma/project/app/utils.ts:379
    value: {startDate: moment().startOf('day').unix() * 1000, endDate: moment().unix() * 1000},

TypeError: moment is not a function
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/roma/project/app/utils.ts:379:29)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
at Module.m._compile (/home/roma/project/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:439:23)
at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .ts] (/home/roma/project/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:442:12)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/roma/project/server/models/user.ts:10:1)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
at Module.m._compile (/home/roma/project/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:439:23)
at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .ts] (/home/roma/project/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:442:12)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

**P.S.** In the future, I still plan to update all packages to the latest versions including node as required by Next.js v11. What is the best and most correct way to do this so that while work is underway to be able to quickly switch to support the site and resolve urgent problems, without facing such a situation as it is now?

Comment: share your package.json file. This could happen due to the incompatible versions of node and its type

Comment: Thanks for responding, I updated my question and added package.json

Comment: In fact, I apparently reinstall incorrectly, I remove the node_modules and yarn-lock folder, then I use the yarn or npm install command, but the typescript version is not the same as in package.json.
yarn-lock file after installation:
"typescript": {
      "version": "3.9.10",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/typescript/-/typescript-3.9.10.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-w6fIxVE/H1PkLKcCPsFqKE7Kv7QUwhU8qQY2MueZXWx5cPZdwFupLgKK3vntcK98BtNHZtAF4LA/yl2a7k8R6Q==",
      "dev": true
    },

Comment: You have `"typescript": "^3.0.1"` in your `package.json`. When using the [`^` (compatible with version)](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/configuring-npm/package-json#dependencies) in the version range you're telling npm to update to all future minor/patch versions, without incrementing the major version. So `^3.0.1` will install `3.9.10`.

Comment: I already figured it out and put specific versions, and also switch them to VSCode, however, I still get the problem, although VSCode does not underline it no matter which version I tell it to use global or local.

It's like when I run "yarn dev" it uses a different typescript at all ...